# Angular Subject called twice with every parsed url

Tags: angular, typescript

My Angular component has `parseStyles` method parses all style-related elements. If it is a link element it proceeds with fetching content of external stylesheet. All works pretty well `console.log('url before next', url)` in `parseStyles` method as expected fires once for every parsed link, but in `map` method `console.log('url in map', url)` is called twice and it points me out that `url$` Subject is worked out twice and it leads to unnecessary double call of `makeRequest` method.

```
export class MyWidgetComponent implements OnChanges { 
  cssExternal$: Observable<any>; 
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const contentChanges = changes.content;
    if (contentChanges) {
      // ...some code
      this.url$ = new Subject();
      this.cssInternal$ = new Subject();

      this.cssExternal$ = this.url$.pipe(
        map((url: string) => {
          console.log('url in map', url);
          if (url.includes(window.location.origin)) {
            return url.replace(window.location.origin, this.url);
          }
          return url;
        }),
        mergeMap((url: string) => {
          return this._ApiService.makeRequest(url, ActionType.content).pipe(
            map(({ content }: any) => content)
          );
        })
      );

      this.css$ = merge(
        this.cssInternal$,
        this.cssExternal$
      );

      this.parseStyles(styleSheets);
    }       

  parseStyles(styleSheets: Element[]) {
    return styleSheets.forEach((element: HTMLElement) => {
      switch (element.localName) {
        // ...some code
        case 'link':
          const url = (element as HTMLLinkElement).href;
          console.log('url before next', url);
          this.url$.next(url);
          break;
        // ...some code
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I provided screenshot to make question clearer [image]

**Edit**.I have added some code that looks important, for resolving

Comment: IMHO it doesn't make sense to make an API call from `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook.

Comment: I make API call whenever the url is changed

Comment: Because you are calling it from the NgOnChanges thats why it's calling it twice

Comment: Why are you creating a new Subject on every change?

Comment: I removed creating a new Subject out of `NgOnChanges`, but it didnt fix an issue